# Windows 10 PowerShell Script to Search Event Viewer for Task Name

Tags: powershell

Would like to create a PowerShell Script that can check the Windows Event Viewer log for the task scheduler.

Specifically for a task starting with say PROD_ and DEV_

Is there a way to use a wildcard for this?

Thanks,

Shane

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to filter on the `Message` property of the [Get-WinEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.diagnostics/get-winevent?view=powershell-7) result:

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName 'Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational' |
    Where message -match 'PROD_|DEV_'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `-like` or any other compare operator.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7